# DB2: Limiting temporary disk space usage by a user or query

Tags: sql, db2, db2-luw

How do I control space consumption by queries in DB2 other than limiting temporary table space container size? The query code itself cannot be touched.

Comment: What DB2 version and platform?

Comment: Win 2008. DB2 9.7 WSE

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like that with [DB2 Workload Management](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.wlm.doc/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.wlm.doc-gentopic1.html) and [thresholds](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.wlm.doc/doc/c0053451.html). There is one threshold for `SQLTEMPSPACE`. You would need to identify the user or query type, then create the related Workload Management objects for that case.

The documentation has some kind of ["starter kit"/tutorial](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.wlm.doc/doc/c0053139.html) that you can use the deploy a WLM scenario and then adapt it to your needs.

Comment: Thank you much :) I'm new to DB2 and need to study this thoroughly

Comment: Note that WLM is only available in Advanced editions.

Comment: Yes, WLM is only available in Advanced editions and this is advanced stuff... :)

Comment: Unfortunately, we don't have advanced.. So creating temp. table space and using DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE is another option?